# how do i get layouts to expand uniformly when window is resized?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

i'm new to GUIs and qt designer, and i just can't figure out why my frames and widgets in don't resize uniformly when the window is resized

heres a gif showing what i mean. https://puu.sh/E6ljI/9038479169.gif . when the window is stretched or shrunk horizontally, the left two frames stretch before the right two. and when stretching vertically, the bottom two stretch before the top two. the expected outcome i want, is to have everything expand and shrink together, so if i expand the window horizontally, everything should expand together at the same rate. ideally, i'd like all 4 frames to be roughly the same sizes so that one frame takes up roughly a quarter of the window regardless of size of the window.

the whole window is in a grid layout, with each quadrant having its own frame (outlined) that stores its contents in a form layout. i've tried messing with changing the size policies but it doesn't have a noticeable difference on how it stretches (at least not that i can see)

if the problem isn't solveable inside qt designer or if it's easier to do in code, i'm using pyuic5 to convert the .ui file created by qt designer into a .py file for use with pyqt5.

link to the .ui file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XY_98QoMGMdbaXPIFsRGxUAoBrHpQg1_

Comment: You can't test layouts properly like that - you need to use preview.

Comment: it's the same when in preview and when running the program

Comment: Add the whole ui file to your question.

Comment: added. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XY_98QoMGMdbaXPIFsRGxUAoBrHpQg1_